# Python shortcut for test key exists and also assign value to variable

Tags: django, variables, conditional-statements, shortcut

Say I have the following code:

```
if request.POST:
   id = request.POST.get('id')
   # block of code to use variable id
   do_work(id)
   do_other_work(id)
```

is there a shortcut (one line of code) that will test if it's request.POST for the conditional block and also assign variable id for the conditional block to use the id variable?

I read this [Is there a Python shortcut for variable checking and assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207333/is-there-a-python-shortcut-for-variable-checking-and-assignment) but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Can you write out the verbose version of this code? I'm a little confused by your wording.

Comment: @Blender I am trying to see if I can do similar to if request.POST and id = request.POST.get('id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't assign anything in an `if` test expression.

If you didn't have the rest of the `if` block,

```
id = request.POST and request.POST.get('id')
```

would work.

It doesn't make much sense, to do it, though, because `id = request.POST.get('id')` works just fine with empty `request.POST`.

Please remember that `request.POST` can be empty, even if the method was `POST`. This is what most people would write:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   id = request.POST.get('id')
   # rest of block
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this:

```
id = request.POST.get('id', False)
if id is not False:
    # do something
```